# How express SQL left join with IS NULL in LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm trying to write a LINQ equivalent of the following SQL:

```
SELECT i.ItemID, i.ItemName 
FROM Items AS i 
LEFT JOIN BillOfMaterials AS bom ON bom.ItemID = i.ItemID
WHERE bom.ItemID IS NULL
```

This returns a set of items where the `itemid` does not appear in the `BillofMaterials.ItemID` column.

I've tried the following which (not surprisingly) doesn't work:

```
from i in ctx.Items 
join b in ctx.BillOfMaterials on i.ItemID equals b.ItemID
into joinedTable
from j in joinedTable.DefaultIfEmpty().Where(w => w.ItemID == null)
select new
{
    i.ItemID,
    i.ItemName
};
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Do you get a compile error, a runtime exception, and/or incorrect results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't seem to be interested here in the actual BOM objects, only if they exist or not, I would recommend using an expression with just an existence check:

```
from i in ctx.Items 
where !ctx.BillOfMaterials.Any(b => i.ItemID == b.ItemID)
select new
{
    i.ItemID,
    i.ItemName
};
```

It is shorter, and it describes better what you are checking for. Also depending on how smart EF is (or not), it could even be more efficient because the `BillOfMaterials` data will never be loaded into .NET memory as `BillOfMaterial` objects.

Comment: You are right that I am not interested in the BOM records themselves - answer accepted for succintness, thank you

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE bom.ItemID IS NULL` in sql corresponds to `j == null` in Linq.
`Where(w => w.ItemID == null)` will not work here, because the `w` was *null* and an exception was thrown.
The right syntax for the *left join* Linq is like :

```
from i in ctx.Items 
join b in ctx.BillOfMaterials on i.ItemID equals b.ItemID into joinedTable
from j in joinedTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
where j == null
select new
{
    i.ItemID,
    i.ItemName
};
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you Sajid, your first suggestion produced the correct results. The second wouldn't compile "An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator'